# Problem uploading files to WSS 3.0 from Office 2010

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication

hopefully someone can help me out with this one. We're using WSS 3.0 with forms based authentication and I'm not able to get it to integrate with Office client app. I'm using Office 2010 and I'm able to open the documents but when I go to save them I get an error stating:
"Upload Failed You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this location"

If I then click on the Sign In button no login screen pops up, Office just tries to upload the document again.

I tried some of the things I found on the net and were suggested for Office 2007 but to no avail.

I'm really hoping that there's some sort of configuration I can tweak to get this working. I'm able to use web folders for example and drag and drop files into libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be our internal proxy which was configured with a pac file. When I removed that option and configured it just like an ordinary proxy it started working.

Was using Office 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your version of Office 2010 is the 32-bit edition.  The 64-bit version is causing problems and it's reported by Microsoft.
[View the blog post](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2010-4-Office_2010_Client_-and-ndash;_Should_I_go_with_32_bit_or_64_bit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration-Application Management, select the site and then click on Authentication Providers, then select the Forms Authentication provider.  Is the "Enable Client Integration" option checked?  If not, check it and try again.  You may have to cycle the app pool and refresh your browser in order for the change to take effect.